# Как передавать содержимое input между страницами в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы на одной странице я мог ввести данные в поле input, а на другой при загрузке страницы эти данные появились на экране.

У меня есть две страницы: первая - с полем ввода и кнопкой, при нажатии на которую проверяется, введено ли что-либо в поле, и если так, то происходит переход на вторую страницу, где содержимое этого поля выводится.

Проблема заключается в том, что вторая страница загружается совершенно пустой. Мне кажется, я неправильно передаю данные. Как это правильно сделать?

Первая страница:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Это сайт</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p align='center'>
        Введите ваше имя:  
        <input type='text' size='25' id='nametxt' />
        <input type='button' value='Применить' onClick='transfer()' />
    </p>
    <script>
        function transfer() {
            var s = document.getElementById('nametxt').value;
            if (s == ''){
                alert('Введите имя');
                return;
            }
            localStorage.setItem('name', s);
            window.location.href = 'welcome.html';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вторая страница:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Приветствие</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id='hello'></p>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'Привет, ' + localStorage['name'];
        localStorage.removeItem( 'objectToPass' );
    </scrpit>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У вас опечатка — не scrpit, а script

Comment: Например, можно чистить содержимое страницы ( JQuery detach() или remove() ) и генерировать блок с результатом, необязательно создавать отдельную страницу или вам принципиален переход?

Comment: Можно открыть вторую страницу get запросом, или сохранить переменную в сессии.